# Ansible - play role even in case of previous failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am building an amazon AMI builder playbook. The idea is:

- spawn up an EC2 instance
- provision it
- register an AMI
- terminate the EC2 instance

I would like to terminate the EC2 instance in any case, even if a previous step failed.

My playbook currently looks like (the spawned EC2 instance is dynamically added to the `ec2_servers` group in the `aws_spawn_ec2` role)):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  roles:
    - role: aws_spawn_ec2
      vars:
        ec2_host_group: ec2_servers


- hosts: ec2_servers
  roles:
    - role: provision_ec2


- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  roles:
    - role: aws_ami_register


- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  roles:
    -role: aws_terminate_ec2
```

I would like the last play to be run even if a previous play failed. Is there a (preferably clean) way of doing that?

[EDIT]
I tried @Z.Liu answer, I got the following error:
`ERROR! 'delegate_to' is not a valid attribute for a IncludeRole`

I then tried that:

```
        - name: provision ec2
          include_role:
            name: provision_ec2
            apply:
              delegate_to: ec2_servers
```

But I now have that error:

```
TASK [provision ec2 : Check if reboot is required] **********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'reboot_required.stat.exists' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (reboot_required.stat.exists): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'"}
```

I have ansible 2.9.10

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. ansible method
   you can leverage ansible `delegate_to` and `block always`

`delegate_to` can let you run the playbook in another hosts

`always` will execute the task regardless of the previous task results.

```
- name: update AMI
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: spawn new ec2 instance
      include_role:
        name: aws_spawn_ec2
      vars:
        ec2_host_group: ec2_servers

    - name: provision only spaw ec2 succeed
      block:
        - name: provision ec2
          include_role:
            name: provision_ec2
          delegate_to: ec2_servers

        - name: registe aws AMI
          include_role:
            name: aws_ami_register
      always:
        - name: terminate ec2 instance regardless of the ami registration results
          include_role:
            name: aws_terminate_ec2
```

---

2. You can also use packer, it is more easily to build the AMI in AWS.
   https://www.packer.io/intro

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I didn't manage to make your suggestion works. I edited my question accordingly. 
We do not want to use packer for out of my scope reasons :)

Comment: @jidey, Oops, I think you put the delegate_to in the wrong level, and there is no need to use apply here. it should be ```- name: provision ec2
          include_role:
            name: provision_ec2
          delegate_to: ec2_servers